# Why is it faster to access database than cached array?

Tags: php, laravel, optimization

I have following (unoptimized) code:

```
public function getFromAllKeys($keyName) {
    ...
    return LokaliseKey::where('key_id', $keyName)->first();
}
```

the page load time is (11.11s) - avg of 5 tries

I access this method around 100 times to search for given key (I know I could optimize it by passing array of keys instead).

Though, if I try to optimize it by defining functionality such as:

```
public function getFromAllKeys($keyName) {
    ...
    $allKeys = Cache::remember('myData', 60, function () {
       return LokaliseKey::all()->keyBy('key_id'); // ± 4000 records
    });

    return Cache::get('myData')[$keyName];
}
```

the page load time is even slower (15.95s)

Comment: Do you men the page load time is slower on the first request or is it slow on each request?

Comment: @AngadDubey when the page is fully loaded

Comment: @kerbholz well the `Cache::remember()` caches the data only if they are already not cached, doesn't it?

Comment: Are you actually using a cache or just simulating one? Larave's default cache is array, which isn't a really good one.

Comment: @IGP I am caching to `file`. I guess I should `redis` or something else but not sure if it's the main issue here.

Comment: 11s on a simple query is a big issue. Regardless, file caching is almost like having no caching at all.